# How to input emojis from files using C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, file-handling

I have the following code,

```cpp
main()
{
    freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    wstring s;
    while(wcin>>s)
    {
            wcout<<s<<" ";
    }
}
```

and the `in.txt` file contains a single emoji . But when I run the following program I get the following output,

```
≡ƒÿé
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the encoding of the file? And what's the default wchar encoding of your platform (UTF-16 on most windows platforms, UTF-32 on most unix)

Comment: The file is in UTF-8, and I am not sure which encoding is default on my pc, but I use Windows 10

Comment: It's a  [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case `'≡ƒÿé'.encode('cp437').decode('utf-8')` returns `''` (and vice versa `''.encode('utf-8').decode('cp437')` returns `'≡ƒÿé'`). Try `chcp 65001` before running the code…